# GROUP values matching criteria to single distinct array

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table with this structure:

> MyObject(***id***, name, category_id, t1, t2, t3, t4);

t1, ... tn are n foreign keys to a table

> MyType(id, name);

Given a category_id, I want a list with all MyType's ids "used" by MyObjects with given category_id.

I can do this via php dissecting the process in some cycles, but I'd rather have a direct SQL approach.

For example:

> MyObject1(***1***, 'q', 1, 1, 2, 3, NULL);
>
> MyObject2(***2***, 'w', 1, 1, 2, NULL, NULL);
>
> MyObject3(***3***, 'e', 2, 5, 3, NULL, NULL);

My expected results are with categoy_id === 1:

> Types = {1,2,3,5}

My expected results are with categoy_id === 2:

> Types = {3,5}

My expected results are with categoy_id === 432:

> Types = {}

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I guess it's simpler than I imagined before, this code solved my needs

```
SELECT t1
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT s.t1 
     FROM MyObject s 
     WHERE s.category_id = 1 AND s.t1 IS NOT NULL) AS q
UNION 
SELECT t2
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT s.t2 
     FROM MyObject s 
     WHERE s.category_id = 1 AND s.t2 IS NOT NULL) AS w
UNION 
SELECT t3
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT s.t3 
     FROM MyObject s 
     WHERE s.category_id = 1 AND s.t3 IS NOT NULL) AS e
UNION 
SELECT t4
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT s.t4 
     FROM MyObject s 
     WHERE s.category_id = 1 AND s.t4 IS NOT NULL) AS r
UNION
SELECT t5
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT s.t5 
     FROM MyObject s 
     WHERE s.category_id = 1 AND s.t5 IS NOT NULL) AS t
ORDER BY t1 ASC
```